# Check if a map contains a specific key in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

In Java:

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
items.put("color", "red");
model.put("items", items);
```

I now want to include a snippet in my rendered template if `items` contains the key `color`.

```
<#if ???? >
   the map contains a key called color
</#if>
```

What do I replace the ???? with?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `??` operator like this:

```
<#if items['color']?? >
   the map contains a key called color
</#if>
```

Comment: Or if the key is really a constant, then just `items.color??`.

Comment: @ddekany that will not work, in case of constant/variable use `items[color]??`

Comment: @Vivek What do you mean again?

Comment: @ddekany i was just correcting you comment just above mine :)

Comment: @Vivek OK, so what I actually meant is that `items['color']??` can be written as `items.color??`.